# PCRE negative lookahead gives unexpected match

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

I want a Perl regular expression to match `std::foo` but not match `std::foo::bar`. This is what I have so far:

```
/((?<!\w)([A-Za-z0-9_]+)::([A-Za-z0-9_]+))(?!:)/
```

This matches `std::foo::bar` as far as `std::fo`, but I want the whole match to fail for this input, not give a partial match.

What regex to I actually want?

Comment: `[A-Za-z0-9_]` is generally written as `\w` if the character set is plain ASCII

Comment: Is this a Perl or PCRE question? You seem to use them interchangeably, but they are different engines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution uses a *possessive quantifer* on the `foo` part of the pattern `\w++`. That means it will refuse to backtrack after finding a series of "word" characters, even if the rest of the pattern -- the negative look-ahead -- then fails. I've also had to change the negative look-behind to reject word characters *or colons `:`* to prevent things like `baz::std::foo` from matching

It is mostly a tidy-up of [the answer from **Sebastian Proske**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42438139/622310). It uses `\w` instead of the literal character class, adds layout using the `/x` modifier, and removes unnecessary parentheses. It also provides a working example

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $s = 'match std::foo but not match std::foo::bar.';

say $1 while $s =~ / (?<![\w:]) ( \w+::\w++) (?!:) /gx;
```

#### output

```
std::foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `\b` before the negative lookahead which ensures that there is an word boundary exisst and also don't forget to add `:` in the first negative lookahead. Otherwise it would match the second part.

```
((?<![:\w])([A-Za-z0-9_]+)::([A-Za-z0-9_]+))\b(?!:)
```

OR

This would match the import string only if it's not preceded by a non-space character.

```
(?<!\S)([A-Za-z0-9_]+)::([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\b(?!:)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gbk31C/1)

Comment: Your second alternative matches something different. I think you should explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Other than `\b` you could also:

- use possessive matching to avoid backtracking into `foo`: `((?<!\w)([A-Za-z0-9_]+)::([A-Za-z0-9_]++))(?!:)`
- add the word character class to the lookahead, so it can't backtrack into `foo`: `((?<!\w)([A-Za-z0-9_]+)::([A-Za-z0-9_]+))(?![:\w])`

Answer (score -1):

To match this whole string `std::foo::bar` instead of partial values
We can use this regex

`((\b(.+)\b)+?[::]{2}.+)`

It will give you two matches

- `std::foo`
- `std::foo::bar`

Comment: `[::]{2}` is nothing more than `::`. But regardless, I don't see how this regex answers the question.

Comment: Or more precisely, `[::]{2}` is a weird way of writing `[:]{2}`, which is a weird way of writing `:{2}`, which is  a weird way of writing `::`.